# How can I do to avoid to make hidden the navbar?

Tags: css, reactjs, leaflet, tailwind-css, react-leaflet

I am working on a project using React, Leaflet, and Tailwind, and I have the following problem:

This is a preview of my project:

[My project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FZ9S.png)

But when I click on the map I get this:

[My problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u0AI.jpg)

I don't see the navbar ...

using Chrome, I noticed I have that behavior since I set this property:

```
html,
body,
#map {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Here is my code in React:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="App overflow-hidden">
        <nav className="bg-white border-gray-200 px-2 sm:px-4 py-2.5 rounded dark:bg-gray-900">
          <div className="container flex flex-wrap justify-between items-center mx-auto">
            <a href="https://flowbite.com/" className="flex items-center">
              <img
                src="https://flowbite.com/docs/images/logo.svg"
                className="mr-3 h-6 sm:h-9"
                alt="Flowbite Logo"
              />
              <span className="self-center text-xl font-semibold whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                Flowbite
              </span>
            </a>
            <button
              data-collapse-toggle="navbar-default"
              type="button"
              className="inline-flex items-center p-2 ml-3 text-sm text-gray-500 rounded-lg md:hidden hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-gray-200 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:focus:ring-gray-600"
              aria-controls="navbar-default"
              aria-expanded="false"
            >
              <span className="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
              <svg
                className="w-6 h-6"
                aria-hidden="true"
                fill="currentColor"
                viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  fillRule="evenodd"
                  d="M3 5a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM3 10a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM3 15a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1z"
                  clipRule="evenodd"
                ></path>
              </svg>
            </button>
            <div
              className="hidden w-full md:block md:w-auto"
              id="navbar-default"
            >
              <ul className="flex flex-col p-4 mt-4 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg border border-gray-100 md:flex-row md:space-x-8 md:mt-0 md:text-sm md:font-medium md:border-0 md:bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 md:dark:bg-gray-900 dark:border-gray-700">
                <li>
                  <a
                    href="/#"
                    className="block py-2 pr-4 pl-3 text-white bg-blue-700 rounded md:bg-transparent md:text-blue-700 md:p-0 dark:text-white"
                    aria-current="page"
                  >
                    Home
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a
                    href="/#"
                    className="block py-2 pr-4 pl-3 text-gray-700 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 dark:text-gray-400 md:dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white md:dark:hover:bg-transparent"
                  >
                    About
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a
                    href="/#"
                    className="block py-2 pr-4 pl-3 text-gray-700 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 dark:text-gray-400 md:dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white md:dark:hover:bg-transparent"
                  >
                    Services
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a
                    href="/#"
                    className="block py-2 pr-4 pl-3 text-gray-700 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 dark:text-gray-400 md:dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white md:dark:hover:bg-transparent"
                  >
                    Pricing
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a
                    href="/#"
                    className="block py-2 pr-4 pl-3 text-gray-700 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 dark:text-gray-400 md:dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white md:dark:hover:bg-transparent"
                  >
                    Contact
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <div
          className="flex-wrap sm:flex-nowrap
                          items-start container flex justify-between items-center mx-auto px-2 sm:px-4 py-2.5"
        >
          <select
            id="countries"
            className="block ml-4 mr-4 mb-2 sm:mb-0 py-2 pr-4 pl-3 bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
          >
            <option selected>Choose a country</option>
            <option value="US">United States</option>
            <option value="CA">Canada</option>
            <option value="FR">France</option>
            <option value="DE">Germany</option>
          </select>
          <select
            id="countries"
            className="block ml-4 mr-4 py-2 pr-4 pl-3 bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
          >
            <option selected>Choose a country</option>
            <option value="US">United States</option>
            <option value="CA">Canada</option>
            <option value="FR">France</option>
            <option value="DE">Germany</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <MapContainer center={[51.505, -0.09]} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={true}>
          <TileLayer
            attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
          <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
            <Popup>
              A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
            </Popup>
          </Marker>
        </MapContainer>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And my code in CSS:

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.leaflet-container {
  width: 100wh;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Could you help me, please?

Thank you very much!

NB : The full project is here : https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-ride-7xjnr6?file=/src/styles.css:0-165

Comment: Set the `.leaflet-container` to 'height:100%` instead of `100vh`

Answer (score 1):

In your css, you are hiding the overflow contents. Removing Overflow hidden in your css will fix your issue.

```
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

Comment: I know that but I want that property overflow on hidden. My problem is that I want both no overflow and no that problem